# Join Dataframes in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have joined two Dataframes in spark using below code -

> Dataframes are: expDataFrame, accountList

```
val expDetails = expDataFrame.as("fex").join(accountList.as("acctlist"),$"fex.acct_id" === $"acctlist.acct_id", "inner")
```

Now I am trying to show both **acct_id** from both dataframe.

I have done below code -

```
expDetails.select($"fex.acct_id",$"acct_id.acct_id").show
```

but getting same column name twice as **acct_id**

I want two unique column name like **fex_acct_id, acctlist_acct_id** to identify the column from which dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to add an alias to the columns using the [`as` or `alias`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#as(java.lang.String)) methods. This will do the job :

```
expDetails.select(
  $"fex.acct_id".as("fex_acct_id"),
  $"acct_id.acct_id".as("acctlist_acct_id")
).show
```